# Dockerfile - escaping env variable passed to a 'RUN' command

Tags: bash, dockerfile

I'm trying to execute the following command

```
RUN printf '{\n\
    "some_key": "'${SOME_VALUE}'"\n\
}' > /something.json
```

The problem is that `SOME_VALUE` contains whitespaces which breaks the printf command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your `RUN` command

```
RUN printf '{\n\
    "some_key": "'${SOME_VALUE}'"\n\
}' > /something.json
```

the shell variable `${SOME_VALUE}` is **unquoted**, and this should always be avoided in practice.

To address this issue, you may want to rely on the format-string features of `printf`, namely:

```
FROM debian:10

ENV VALUE_A="a \n a"
ENV VALUE_B="b \n b"

RUN printf '{"key_a": "%s",\n "key_b": "%s"}' "${VALUE_A}" "${VALUE_B}" > /something.json

CMD cat /something.json
```

Note in particular that the variables above are quoted (`"${VALUE_A}"`, not `${VALUE_A}`).

For more information on the syntax of the `printf` shell builtin, see:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13
(e.g., you might be interested in the `%b` format string in lieu of `%s`…)

**Disclaimer:** the revised code still won't produce proper JSON code if the variables contain some `"`s.